# Generate and Install APK file programmatically

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I am creating the android projects using my custom wizard and it will give complete android project. Now i want to do the following,

1. `create the .apk file for the generated android application`, when the user clicks the button "**Generate APK**"
2. `find the connected android devices`, `choose the specific device` and `install the generated .apk file` (from 1st step) when the user clicks the button "**Install into Device**"

Guide me please

Comment: I did not tried anything, this is the first time for this scenario

Comment: Could you please tell me why given Close request for this question then only i can find my mistake.

Comment: `please tell me why given Close ...` - question is too broad . `gradle - what is this? how to use this?` did google stop working?